# find a post against its description using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Friends I just want to show a single `post` against its `description`.

On my `home page` I have all the `descriptions` and when a `user` clicks any `description` then `user` should be redirected to its respective `post`.

I have two models one for `Post` and `Descrip`.

*Descrip belongs_to Post* 
and 
*Post has_one Descrip*

I just want to know that if user clicks on any description then on next page a post should appear related to that description.

Kindly help or suggest me how i can do that. At this time I just get all the posts when user click a description link. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have partial file which i render to my home page.This partila file have a link button as below

```
<% @post.reverse_each do |post| %>
  <li>
    <p>
     <%= descrip.description %>
   </p>
  <%=link_to 'APPLY TO THIS JOB', descriptions_view_path, :class => 'read_more pull_rigt' %>
<% end %>
```

View.html.erb where i render my partial file look like this

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: { post: Post.all} %>
```

and posts controller have two methods

```
def show
  redirect_to post_path(Post.all) and return
end
def index
  @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
end
```

and description controller have a view method

```
def view
  @descrip = Descrip.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
  @post = Post.all  
end
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code in the question otherwise there are high chances of your question getting closed. It looks like you already tried some code but its showing incorrect results. Post that code here.

Comment: thanks for reply. Can u please guide me that how i can find a post against a description.I dont know which code i should post as i have two controllers of posts and descriptions.

Comment: Add the view code on which you have the description link. Also, add the controller specific code i.e., the action called upon clicking the link. Update your question with these two so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for guidance.I have edit my post kindly help me to sort out my problem.I just want to show a single post against a description.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "descriptions#index"
resources :descriptions

#app/controllers/descriptions_controller.rb
def index
   @descriptions = Description.all
end
def show
   @description = Description.find params[:id]
end

#app/models/description.rb
Class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :post
end

#app/views/descriptions/index.html.erb
<% for description in @descriptions do %>
   <%= link_to description.title, description_path(description.id) %>
<% end %>

#app/views/descriptions/show.html.erb
<%= @description.post %>
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Rich Peck. I will try this soon and let you know about results.